# imwrite - A file name must be supplied

Tags: matlab, syntax-error

I have the following `imwrite` statement:

```
imwrite(img, strcat(thisdir,'_',num2str(j),'_LABEL_',categoryClassifier.Labels(labelIdx),'.jpg'));
```

where `categoryClassifier.Labels(labelIdx)` returns a `string`, and `thisdir` is also a `string` returning the directory name. But, I get the following error:

```
Error using imwrite>parse_inputs (line 510)
A filename must be supplied.

Error in imwrite (line 418)
   [data, map, filename, format, paramPairs] = parse_inputs(varargin{:});
```

Isn't the part from `strcat` considered the filename?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you show an example of what that `strcat()` produces?

Comment: @user1877862. When I replaced the variables which are expected to produce strings, for instance: strcat(thisdir,'_',num2str(1),'_LABEL_','image','.jpg') ---> mri_1_LABEL_image.jpg

Answer (score 1):

This is kinda a shot in the dark, but I suspect that you want `categoryClassifier.Labels{labelIdx}` rather than `categoryClassifier.Labels(labelIdx)` (the difference is the curly braces).

Assuming that `categoryClassifier.Labels` is a cell array of strings, the curly braces give you the contents of that cell (which is what you want), whereas the parentheses give you a 1x1 cell array (which looks a lot like a string in MATLAB's command window). Note also that `strcat` is perfectly happy to process a cell array of strings, so it doesn't complain, but `imwrite` freaks out because none of its arguments are a string.